# Postfix Smtp host resolve issue

Tags: networking, server, email, postfix, mail

I'm fine tuning my Postfix/Dovecot installation on my Ubuntu server and I'd like to fix this warning I keep receiving:

> Feb 14 14:43:25 mail postfix/smtps/smtpd[4035]: warning: hostname
>   217-221-73-77-static.albacom.net does not resolve to address
>   217.221.73.77: Name or service not known Feb 14 14:43:25 mail postfix/smtps/smtpd[4035]: connect from unknown[217.221.73.77]

Everything is working fine but I'd like to understand what is causing the issue. I already checked that in my hosts.conf i have the line

```
multi on
```

that many indicates as the root cause of this warning (if it is missing) but in my case it is not. I'm not attaching my conf files for postfix and dovecot since I don't have a clue on where to spot the light on actually. Feel free to request any furhter detail!

Comment: You *can't* fix it. It is not a problem on your end - it is a problem with the remote end not having DNS configured correctly.

Comment: You can find an answer here: http://serverfault.com/a/826478/355817

Comment: @vidarlo what do you mean with "remote end"? I am speaking about logs I have on my smtp server...

Answer (score 0):

"remote end" is this context means the ISP of your server. i.e. the people who provide internet access for your server.
unless the domain of your sender is `static.albacom.net` then your server is misconfigured for reverse DNS PTR records.
The way you solve that is to contact your host/ISP and get them to setup reverse DNS for your domain.
It looks like you also have a problem with how you  are sending the mail, at the beginning of the SMTP exchange with the MTA, your email client is not declaring the proper sender host. it should be the host (domain) of the sender.
Also, it looks like you havent provided the correct sender host at the email client end, so postfix is just applying `217.221.73.77` as a fallback.

Comment: No. Remote end means that the other end has not set up reverse DNS properly, and postfix logs this as a warning. The remote end sends a hostname, and postfix tries to resolve it. It can't so it logs a warning saying that it coudn't. It's literally nothing you can do about it - except perhaps block clients that doesn't supply a proper hostname.